# Swift what is correct syntax of dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
 var myCountry:String?
var myCity:String?
var myBodyType:String?
var myOrientation:String?
var myRelationship:String?
```

I need to build a dictionary variable from this data but the myCountry and myCity I want to combine under the one key "region". I tryed:

```
var myData = ["region":["country":myCountry,"city":myCity],"bodyType":myBodyType,"orientation":myOrientation,"relationship":myRelationship]
```

its wrong. how to do this?

Answer (score 12):

Basically the syntax is correct, but ...

...in Swift 3 you get this error:

> heterogenous collection literal could only be inferred to '[String : Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional

That means you have to write

```
var myData : [String:Any] = ["region" ...
```

Consider also to handle the optionals because in Swift a `nil` value means *the key is missing*.